# Microsoft Graph Api batch update

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I am using 6.1.0 version of Microsoft Graph API , I want to update a particular mail property (`isRead`) to true, I want to do this in a single network call using batch update.

I am unable to find the code/example for it on the GitHub repo or the Microsoft web site. Please help if anyone knows.

```java
System.out.println("Before...");

boolean before =
graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(user_id).messages().byMessageId(msgId).get().getIsRead();

System.out.println(before);

Message messageToUpdate = new Message();

boolean val = !before;

messageToUpdate.setIsRead(val);

//update        
graphServiceClient.users().byUserId(user_id).messages().byMessageId(msgId).patch(messageToUpdate);


System.out.println("After...");

System.out.println(client.byUserId(user_id).messages().byMessageId(msgId).get().getIsRead());`
```

This is working for single `msgId`, I want to do a list of multiple ids in the batch form.

Please note the I version I am using is 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK should support sending batch request. In each batch, you can specify at least 20 requests.

Example below is for one request in the batch, but to add more you will probably use some loop to create patch request information

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setIsRead(true);

// Create a batch request content object
BatchRequestContent batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent(graphClient);

// Create patch request via RequestInformation
RequestInformation patchMessage = graphClient.users("{userId}").messages("{message-id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .toPatchRequestInformation(message);

// Add the request to the batch request content
// The id of the request is returned, can be used later to retrieve the specific response for that request    
String patchMessageRequestId = batchRequestContent.addBatchRequestStep(patchMessage);

// Send the batch request
BatchResponseContent responseContent = graphClient.getBatchRequestBuilder().post(batchRequestContent, null);
```

To add more requests, simply create another request information via `toPatchRequestInformation` and call `addBatchRequestStep`.

The doc: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v6.md#batch-requests

Comment: Hi, thanks , the above code is working fine but graphServiceClient.getBatchRequestBuilder().post(batchRequestContent,null);
Is going like an infinite loop. 

The .post is giving a timeout any specific reason for that

Comment: Not sure, I'm not familiar with JAVA SDK. In that case I would suggest to raise a new ticket for SDK: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues